# Issue receiving a mysql_query

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to check if a specific link is already contained in a database, 
but I keep getting an error stating "mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource" 
I've tried changing a lot of things, but nothing seems to work. Can anybody help?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `songs` WHERE `link` = '$link'");
if($result == False){
   "echo f3";
    return False;
   }
$count =mysql_num_rows($result);
if($count > 0){
   echo "f4", $count;
   return False;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqli_*` is not the same as `mysql_*`. You can't use resource from one in another.

Use `mysqli_num_rows()` to get number of rows from mysqli resource.